# How to use wildcards in firestore cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use a wildcard in a cloud function with firestore like this:

```
exports.function_name= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
return admin.firestore().collection('users/messages/{messageCollectionId}')
```

but it does not work. It works if I use an actual id, instead of the wildcard. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: Hello Frank. I was expecting to delete messages every certain amount of time. I think this can be done with firebase. However, I need firestore in this case.

Answer (score 7):

There are no wildcards in Firestore paths to documents for the purpose of querying from client code.  You have to identify collections and documents by their IDs.  If you need to find some documents based on some property, you'll need to do a query using some field value as a filter.

You might be confused by wildcards in Cloud Functions trigger paths.  When you define a Firestore trigger function, you can use a wildcard to determine which documents would trigger that function, but you can't use them with the client SDKs to locate documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug. I thought this was posible.

Comment: It's definitely not possible.

Comment: @DougStevenson Are you sure? I'm running into the same issue and I'm only following the Google documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore

Comment: @kashiB Yes, I'm sure.  You're looking at documentation for Firestore triggers, which is a different thing.  That's not a client library you use to query the database.  It's a mechanism that you use to have code execute when something happens to a document. To OP here is apparently trying to write a an HTTP function that queries their database using the Admin SDK and returns the results - but you can't query a database with a wildcard in the document path, and you likely never will be.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what do you want to do. But you DO can use wildcards like this:

You can use wildcard on Firebase functions by accessing on context.

```
exports.function_name= functions.firestore.document('users/messages/{messageCollectionId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const messageCollectionId = context.params.messageCollectionId;
  console.log('my messageCollectionId: ${messageCollectionId});
});
```

In your example I don't know why would you use wildcard. Isn't just a var variable?

```
exports.function_name= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const messageCollectionId = req.params.id;
  admin.firestore().collection('users/messages/${messageCollectionId}')
});
```

Read more: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/extend-with-functions

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting to delete messages every certain amount of time

You can use [TTL](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/databases/-default-/ttl): Just create a new rule and assign a timestamp field to this rule.

Or perhaps you can use a [scheduled function](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler). Here's a little example:

```
// runs every week day at 09:00 in Brazil timezone
exports.notifications = functions
  .region( 'southamerica-east1' )
  .pubsub
  .schedule( 'every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 09:00' )
  .timeZone( 'America/Sao_Paulo' )
  .onRun( async () => {
      
    // handle here your data fetch, manipulation, deletion, etc....

    return null
  } )
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this comment to help others in the same situation.

Firebase don't provide a way to use "wildcards" into the collection path, but I created a tiny Python function to retrieve documents/collections matching a given expression with wildcards.

[Firebase - Firestore collection - Using wildcards](https://gist.github.com/LuchoLopez/c649dbfc01703a3828a40a2a08ac34ba)

```
 def replace_wildcards(db_client, collection_path: str):
    """
    Returns a generator with all the elements paths matching the collection expression.
    Wildcards are allowed: So, you can use 'user/*/collection/*/subcollection/*' to retrieve all the
    documents matching that expression.
    """
    collection_parts = collection_path.split('*')
    if len(collection_parts) == 1:
        yield collection_parts[0]
    else:
        to_replace = collection_parts[0].rstrip('/')
        documents = db_client.collection(to_replace).list_documents()
        for element in documents:
            new_collection_path = f"{element.path}/{'*'.join(collection_parts[1:])}".replace('//', '/')
            is_collection = len(new_collection_path.rstrip('/*').split('/')) % 2 != 0
            if is_collection:
                yield from self.replace_wildcards(new_collection_path)
            else:
                yield new_collection_path.rstrip('/')
```